# Draw a shape ( drawable ) using xml on android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, xml-drawable, android-shape

I would like to draw the following shape ( without border ) using xml on android studio. Could anyone please help me to draw it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the xml to your Drawable Folder. set android:scrCompat="@drawable/whateverItIsCalled" in ImageView xml

Comment: But I need to draw it first. I need some help to draw it.

Comment: What do you mean with "draw". ImageView will draw the .png file

Comment: I want to write some xml code so that It finally looks like the sample image.